# Number of arcs in undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

It is a basic question in graph theory!

I have *n* nodes and I would like to calculate the number of paths among *n* nodes so that each node appears once in a path. I think it is Hamilton cycle, but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require that the path begins and ends at the same node, but do require that it visits each node *exactly* once, then what you're looking for is the number of **Hamiltonian paths** in the graph.

The is a hard problem -- in fact, even finding out whether the number of such paths is $0$ or $\ge 1$ is NP-complete. Therefore you shouldn't expect to find a feasible *general* approach to the problem.

If you have a concrete graph you want to count Hamiltonian paths in, what you need is some clever approach tailored to that particular graph (or to a particular class of graphs that it belongs to).

Comment: Thanks @Henning. What if we don't require to visit each node exactly once?

Comment: @rezi: Then there are generally infinitely many paths (it the graph is connected, of course) -- nothing would prevent you from going back and forth between to neighboring nodes for as long as you want before making separate trips out to each ot the nodes.

Comment: If you're asking about paths that visit all nodes _and are shorter than some specified length_, you get back into NP-complete territory

Comment: @ Henning: I want to enumerate the routes among 5 cities in a vehicle routing problem ; however, I found similar problem that say for 8-node 109,600 paths and for 10-node problem 9,864,100 paths exist. I would like to realize how they calculate these numbers. I think those are not Hamilton cycle.

Comment: @rezi: $109,600$ and $9,864,100$ is the number of nonempty sequences drawn from and 8- or 10-element set such that each element appears _at most once_, but where not all elements need to appear at all. Those are not Hamiltonian. But if that is what you're looking for, then a general formula is $e\cdot n!-1$, rounded down the the nearest integer. (Here $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm, $2.71828...$).

Comment: @ Henning  thank you so much for your help! excellent!

Comment: @ Henning, if I want to have a 5-node problem with some conditions for instance; each element appears at most once and not all elements need to appear , as well as only 3 elements can appear in a sequence. In this case should I add ${5}\choose{3}$ to the general formula? thank you again!

Comment: @rezi: Then you get something like $\frac{5!}{(5-1)!}+\frac{5!}{(5-2)!}+\frac{5!}{(5-3)!}$, since $\frac{5!}{(5-n)!}$ is the number of sequences of length _exactly_ $n$ that don't repeat any element. I'm not sure if there is a slick way to combine that into a single expression, but if your numbers are as small as this, just computing the sum directly should do.

Comment: @ Henning, if the number of routes do not visit more than 3 nodes, the above formulation is still valid?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are asking for the number of Hamiltonian Cycles in a graph. If youre allowed to go from any node to any other, than the number of such paths is the number of orderings of the nodes. You have $n$ choices for the first node, $n-1$ for the second, and so on. Therefore you have $n!$ such paths.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, a path that visits every node(vertex) once is called a Hamilton path. If this path, ends on the same vertex it started it is called a Hamilton cycle.

The number of Hamilton paths will depend on the edges that connect these vertices(nodes). For a general graph, finding a Hamilton path is NP-complete: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness, that is, there are no known algorithms that solve the problem in polynomial time. There are several known algorithms that run in exponential time here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem.

Comment: Thanks @Lazopard. What if we don't require to visit each node exactly once?